# A little bit of encryption

Tags: cipher

A little selfmade encryption riddle:

Whenever I'm  searching for a solution, I have this feeling,
like standing on a single point.
While I take a step forward, I have the feeling I'm falling two steps behind.
It never matters how far I go, in the end I always stand where I started.

Can you solve this?

```
Et tu, Brute?
ucoh ry tq ohtsap, lrrb kaiw tkshpsw bjya?
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Et tu, Brute? refers to

> the betrayal of Caesar by Brutus, hence suggesting a Caesar shift.

Following the story intro:

> "While I take a step forward, I have the feeling I'm falling two steps behind" -> Let's perform escalating and alternating Caesar shifts letter by letter. 1 step forward, 2 steps back, 3 steps forward, etc, except flip the directions because we're decoding instead of encoding.

The decoded cipher is

> **tell me my friend, what runs without feet?**

which could be answered by

> a river, anything electric or motored, your nose, or many other things